# Xubuntu 17.04 Laptop lid close not recognized

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, laptop

Suspend on laptop lid close has never worked on this install and it appears that it is **not** due to the really common bug described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1574120) when acpi improperly expecting a laptop to be docked.

Instead it looks like the power manager is not catching the lid close at all. The lid state is being stored in /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state and tailing that gives:

```
sarai@ninjacer:~$ tail -f /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state
state:      open
tail: /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state: file truncated
state:      open
```

But closing the lid with that running should change the file, no? Nothing additional gets written when I close and reopen the lid.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Same issue here. I'll be watching this

Comment: same issue for me. Just to mention, I had to type `tail -f /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state`